# SQL get max record that is less than or equal to a datetime paramter

Tags: sql

In SQL I'm trying to get most recent record for example (the max record which is less than or equal to a `datetime` parameter passed)

For example in my table called `serviceentry` there is a column called `ServiceDateTime`

How do I apply Max in my select clause. So in the following if a part has a service entry, I want to get the max record based on my datetime parameter

```
select  
    Part.System as Subsystem, Part.ID as PartNumber, 
    Part.PartDescription, System.SystemFullName,
    COALESCE(ServiceEntryPart.PartRevisionNumber, Part.RevisionNumber) AS Revision
from 
    Part
left outer join 
    ServiceEntryPart on Part.ID = ServiceEntryPart.PartID
left outer join 
    ServiceEntry on ServiceEntryPart.ServiceEntryID = ServiceEntry.ID
left outer join 
    System on System.PlatformID = Part.platformid
where
    part.id = 670220
    and ServiceEntry.ServiceDateTime <= '1/1/2014'
```

Comment: Based on your expression, you are returning all columns from `Records`; nothing was expressed to return the max record. Are you having rows returned from the statement?

Comment: yes sorry, But do I have to select one column if I do MAX?

Comment: There is a `MAX()` function which you can use to specify the column as a parameter which indicates the row you wish to return.

Comment: @user721, max on which column ?

Comment: @use721, Ron.B.I answer should work in that case, you can apply top 1 here also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Simple solution - only needs 1 record:

This does the trick:

`select TOP 1 * from myTable where myDate <= @SomeDate order by se.ServiceDateTime desc`

### Complete solution - more than 1 suitable record:

Just in case you need **all** the records that have the max value that is less or equal to a given parameter, consider the following, *awful, yet gets the point across*, example for a solution:

**Example:**

```
CREATE TABLE Parts 
(
 id int auto_increment primary key,
 part_name varchar(10),
 buyer varchar(10)
);

CREATE TABLE Purchase 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key,
     buyer varchar(10),
     purchase_date datetime
    );

INSERT INTO Parts (part_name, buyer)
VALUES ('hammer','mc'), ('wrench','larry'), ('screw','bill');

INSERT INTO Purchase (buyer, purchase_date)
VALUES ('mc','2012-01-01 22:00'), ('larry', '2014-01-01 22:00'), ('bill', '2012-01-01 22:00');


SET @my_date ='2013-01-01 22:00';
select pa.buyer as buyer , purchase_date, pa.part_name as part_name
      from Parts pa 
      left outer join Purchase pu on (pa.buyer = pu.buyer)
      inner join (
        select max(purchase_date) max_date from Purchase where purchase_date <= @my_date) md 
        on md.max_date = pu.purchase_date
```

[Sql Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fc9de/23)

Comment: that works, I know I did not specify in the original post, If my condition is in a query which is doing couple of joins, i cant seem to apply max

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried? seems like you may have some other issue. because in any case it should always be possible, yet not always needed, to wrap things up with some select query.

Comment: Original solution works for initial edit, added another for completeness sake.

Comment: hey there thanks for that, I have another, if you want to take a look thats great, But I am basically trying to get top 1 record in a pivot column field value and i added the top1 in my sql but its a little more comples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582703/sql-dynamic-pivot-column-in-the-columns-row-value-how-to-get-top-1-value

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something like this myself just now using PostgresSQL - I chose this way: (context: in a trading simulator over past year, get id of timestamped money management book that is latest before the trading date next in a one year loop of trading simulation)
the first ? will be a ticker and the second the trading date. For MSSQL you would replace the limit 1 by a set rowcount = 1 before the query.

```
    select mmgb_id from mmgr_book
    where mmgb_shortname = ? 
    and mmgb_infodate <= ?
    order by mmgb_infodate DESC
    limit 1
```